# Retrieving data from a node.js data service layer module?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have created a module and this module has a function that retrieves data from mongodb, now suppose I have a function that returns a JSON objects and I am going to call this function from another module.

DataServiceLayer.js:

```
function getData(id) {
     ...;
     return data;
}
```

App.js:

```
function retrieve(callback) {
     var fetchedData = callback;
     console.log(fetchedData);
}

retrieve(require('./DataServiceLayer')(id))
```

However, I always get an undefined variable for fetchedData which I guess because of the Async process that node.js does, how can I get my result and print it out?

Thanks

Comment: hey thanks for the quick response, but the getData function in the DSL module is just fetching data from the db, and the retrieve method call the only one function in the DSL module so maybe you want more code in the App.js module ?

Comment: I wanted to know more about the getData function. The golden rule is - Don't return from Async functions, use callbacks. Once you understand callbacks well enough and want to avoid callback hells move the Promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... with limited info provided... I can only give you a generic answer.

In data.js

```
// In general, yopu give callbacks to Async functions.
// In node callbacks have signature - callback( error, result )
function getData( id, callback ) {
    someAsyncGetDataFunction( {id : id}, callback );
}

module.exports = getData;
```

In App.js

```
var getDataFunc = require( './data' )

function retrieveAndLogToConsole( id ) {
    var myCallback = function( err, result ) {
        if ( err ) { console.log( "error" ); }
        else { console.log( result ); } 
    }

    getDataFunc( id, myCallback );
}
```

Comment: finally got it working, thanks mate, and to be very honest with you I am still new to node and I come from Java World since 9 years for now so the single thread mode thingy is not yet their in my mind :P , but thanks now I guess I have acquired a full understanding of the callbacks :D , cheerz

Answer (score 0):

How about doing in this way

DataServiceLayer.js:

```
getData(id){........}
module.exports.getData = getData;
```

App.js

```
var getData = require('./DataServiceLayer.js').getData;
function retrive(id){
    return getData(id);
}
```